# Is it possible to kill stuck threads in Weblogic?

Tags: windows, weblogic12c

I'm having a Weblogic server with one Admin Server and 3 managed servers in a single cluster. ADF application is deployed in this cluster. I'm getting stuck threads intermittently in one of the managed servers. Is there any way to kill these threads which got stuck? I don't want to hinder the activities of the users in another managed servers. I just want to kill the thread associated with that particular user whose application that got stuck. Is this possible?
I'm using Windows OS. 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Stuck threads cannot be killed.
All you can do is to find the root cause and fix it. Make a thread dump and analyse it.

Check [this](http://oraclemiddlewareblog.com/2014/06/10/dealing-stuck-threads-weblogic/) link for some guidance.